# in cmake use find_package to find glog success,but get empty glog_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: windows, cmake, glog

I use cmake in vs2019.gflags,glog,libevent use vs2019 to compile and installed before,find_package can find those three packages,but only gflags_INCLUDE_DIR has value,glog_INCLUDE_DIR and libevent_INCLUDE_DIR are both empty.
cmake info:

```
find_package (gflags)
if (NOT gflags_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "gflags not found")
endif()
message(WARNING "gflags include path:"   ${gflags_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package (glog)
if (NOT glog_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "glog not found")
endif()
message(WARNING "glog include path:"   ${glog_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package (libevent)
if (NOT libevent_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libevent not found")
endif()
message(WARNING  "libevent include path:" ${libevent_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

out put:

```
1> [CMake] CMake Warning at D:\git\DBStream\CMakeLists.txt:54 (message):
1> [CMake]   gflags include path:D:/git/gflags/out/install/x64-Debug/include
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] CMake Warning at D:\git\DBStream\CMakeLists.txt:60 (message):
1> [CMake]   glog include path:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] CMake Warning at D:\git\DBStream\CMakeLists.txt:66 (message):
1> [CMake]   libevent include path:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] -- Found libevent 2.2.0 in D:/git/libevent/out/build/x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] -- Generating done
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: D:/git/DBStream/out/build/x64-Debug
```

Comment: It depends on which `Findglog.cmake` script you use, but most of `FindXXX.cmake` scripts set variable `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` (note on the terminated 's'). Also, instead of checking `XXX_FOUND` variable with following `message(FATAL_ERROR)` is is better to call `find_package()` with REQUIRED keyword. E.g. `find_package (glog REQUIRED)`. That way CMake by itself prints error message if the package wasn't found.

Comment: thank you,I have add REQUIRED in find_package ,and now i use SET(glog_INCLUDE_DIR ${glog_DIR}/include) to solve the problem.